# Why isn't the same class List created in C#?

Tags: c#, list, listview

I am trying to create a `List` of same class, but I am unable to create the `List` of this. It throws the following error

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52906526/edit) your question and add code as text, not image. Also add exception message and stack trace

Comment: Please post code. Inparticular incldue the code where you define and assign the variable `lstProduct`

Comment: List does not have method named `add`. Use `Add(product1)` instead

Comment: Looks like you are trying to call Add() on the List in the class scope. Call it within method or constructor

Comment: Ad should start with a capital letter not a small letter.

Comment: What @VladL said is your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lstProduct.Add(yourprocudtvar)`

note the capital A, you also need to add a product, right now your not adding anything.

Comment: This is not the problem. See what VladL says

Comment: Yes this issue is solved.. thanx to vladl